# vsftp on Azure VM - filezilla reports private ip sent by server in passive mode

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, azure, vsftpd

I'm setting up a secure FTP server on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine on Azure. It's FTP over TLS, with anonymous access disabled.

Trying to use the server using Filezilla works fine - authentication, transfer, directory listing - everything... except I get the following warning from Filezilla:

> Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server
>   address instead.

Sure, that makes sense - the VM has a private IP address, and in passive mode, it sends that private IP address to the client. The solution - add the following to vsftp.conf (this is an example, not the actual configuration):

```
pasv_enable=YES
port_enable=YES
#The VM allows connections to ports 12345 & 12346 - remember, this is an example
pasv_min_port=12345 
pasv_max_port=12346
#The VM's domain name
pasv_address=myftpservervm.cloudapp.net
#Make vsftp resolve myftpservervm.cloudapp.net and send that IP address to clients
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
```

Then I restart vsftp, and... nothing happens. I still get these:

> Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server
>   address instead.

I even tried setting `pasv_address` to the exact (external) IP address of the server (with and without `pasv_addr_resolve=YES`) and the result is the same.

**Am I missing something?**

I'm using vsftpd 3.0.3 (from the Ubuntu repo) with Filezilla 3.24.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Edit:

Apparently vsftp sends an IP address of `0.0.0.0` when entering passive mode. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046707/vsftpd-returns-0-0-0-0-in-response-to-pasv) issue seems relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test in my lab, at first I met the same problem as you. I checked as the following steps:

1.`netstat -ant` I get the following result

```
tcp6       0      0 172.17.1.4:21           167.220.255.56:10979    TIME_WAIT
```

Based on my experience, ftp should be listening on `tcp` not `tcp6` on Azure VM

2.I try to change the configuration file `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

```
listen=yes
listen_ipv6=no
```

Then I restart ftp service and check by using `netstat -ant`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

3. Test by using Filezilla.

[image]

**Notes: You should open ports 20,21,12345-12346 on Azure NSG(Inbound rule)**

Answer (score 1):

You need just a minor modification. Edit /etc/vsftpd.conf or whatever the config file might be, and do this change:

```
pasv_address=public_ip_of_aws_instance_not_hostname_or_private_ip
```

Save the file, restart the vsftpd service and check again!

Be sure that hose passive ports are in the tcp allow list in your Security Groups (you can configure those from your AWS EC2 Dashboard).

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I tried both the external IP, and the domain name (with `pasv_addr_resolve=YES`). It produced the same result.